# How do I remove the "Welcome to the developer portal" section of APIM's Developer Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

On the developer portal's home page for my APIM instance, there's a section in between the section links at the top of the page (HOME, APIS, PRODUCTS, APPLICATIONS, ISSUES), and the Welcome page content below. It looks like this:

[image]

I can't find anything for it in the Publisher Portal. In the `Manage Content` section, there's the Welcome Page, but that just defines what's under this section I want to remove. In the developer portal, there's no template category that seems to map to this. Is there any way for me to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Developer Portal, go to **Administrator -> Manage -> Widgets** (from left nav) and choose "**Home Page**" from **Current Layer** dropdown and click **SHOW**.

Page will refresh and display the current layout of your home page [of dev portal.]

Section you're looking to remove is the one called "Banner" which is in the Featured section so you can just remove that.

Follow this for more info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-modify-content-layout